# Is it safe to deploy a 8,000,000 gas contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-limit

`8,000,000` gas seems to be the maximum gas allowed when deploying a contract on mainnet.

My question is, is it even safe to do so or do I have a bigger risk that my deployment tx  fails ? If so I would loose my consumed gas at every failed attempt.

- Do I need to take a margin ? (say `7,500,000` ??)
- Do I need to put high gas price to be sure to be included in next block in priority?
- I see [the latest blocks](https://etherscan.io/block/13457448) with `30,000,000` gas limit, so does the `8,000,000` limit only applies to deploying contracts ? (if so `8,000,000` should be safe !)

gn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the transaction is under the current Ethereum consensus rules it should be allowed.

But miners have the final decision some might prefer to exclude large transactions unless the gasPrice is above average, other probably won't care.

You can start sending it with above average gasPrice and then increasing it by 10 percentage until it is mined or the cost is too much.